# How to extract a folder from a TypeScript module and properly reference its classes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg

I am working on a Yarn/Node/TypeScript project, and I need to restructure the directory of one of the modules, say `module_a`. Currently, there is a subfolder within `module_a` called sdk, and I want to extract sdk to the root level, which means I would have two separate folders: `module_a` and `sdk`.

After extracting sdk, there will be classes in `module_a` that need to reference classes in sdk. What is the best way to update the references?

Additionally, do I need to create all the boilerplate configuration files for the sdk folder such as *tsconfig.json*, *package.json*, etc.?

Comment: Are they two separate projects/modules now?

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger what I was ask for is to turn the `sdk` folder into a reusable module, but I don't know what it means in practical terms, like, if I should have all of those configs or just a folder with .ts files.

Comment: Ok, I'd make it standalone, so with all configs. And then optionally publish it to npm. This way you can npm install it whatever you want. This translates well if you want to publish module_a or any other module that requires sdk, on npm as well. But I'd be cautious, only do this once sdk is somewhat mature, as you will need to test it independently of module_a when developing it further. If you just want to work on your local machine and never want to publish anything, you could move the tsconfig to the root level. I dont think its a great idea to reach below tsconfig level for dependencies.

Comment: @MaximilianMairinger which means that, if I want to use classes on `sdk` folder I need to import them thorugh a npm library? or just make a reference to the file? thanks for your help.

Comment: Which classes from where? From module_a? module_a depending on sdk and sdk depending on module_a is a little dangerous. Or did you mean external dependencies? In that case probably yes, but then I dont really understand the question. In either case it would help to know which option you chose, and what you mean with "want to use classes"